# Erro ao fazer teste Shapiro Wilk em multiplas colunas do dataframe

Tags: r

Eu tenho três dataframes, um principal, com 2046 observações e dois derivados desses (com 1980 e 66 observações respectivamente) que representam empresas solventes e insolventes.
Todos os dataframes apresentam 48 variáveis incluindo identificação e período, ou seja, estou tentando realizar o teste em apenas 46 colunas.
No dataframe completo eu consigo rodar o teste normalmente, contudo, nos dataframes menores aparece o mesmo erro:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : all 'x' values are identical

O código que estou usando tanto para os dataframes menores quanto o maior é esse:

```
Data_SW <- do.call(rbind, lapply(Data[c(3:41)], shapiro.test))
Data_SW <- data.frame(Data_SW)
```

Uma sugestão que me deram foi a seguinte:

```
num <- which(sapply(Completo[3:50], is.numeric))
num <- intersect(3:50, num)

Completo_SW <- do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(Completo[num], function(x){
    tryCatch(shapiro.test(x)[c("statistic", "p.value")],
             error = function(e) e)
  })
)
```

Mas o erro persiste, o que eu posso fazer para corrigir isso?
Já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Já corrigi o erro no [SO em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65601436/8245406). Veja agora se está bem.